# Полифилл для отображения (не рисования!) svg в IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, svg

Нужно чтобы отображалась произвольная svg-иконка, приходящая из внешнего источника. Рисовать самому ничего векторного не надо. Существует ли такой полифилл для IE8?

Answer (score 1):

[Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) умеет работать с VML для старых IE. Попробуйте воспользоваться им.

Comment: Эм.. Мне казалось, Рафаэль нужен для рисования - создаётся его холст, на котором можно рисовать фигуры, а он уже сам решает, в каком виде это скормить браузеру - svg или vml. А мне нужно отобразить присланную сервером svg-иконку, а не рисовать фигуры руками. Он это тоже может? Если да, можно пример или более конкретную ссылку на описание?

Comment: Посмотрите, должно помочь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926643/raphael-js-use-a-svg-file

Comment: [raphael-svg-import-classic](https://github.com/crccheck/raphael-svg-import-classic) - возможно, подойдёт.